# Can I charge a motorcycle / car battery with an external AGM battery, a step-up, a MOSFET, and one potentiometer?

Tags: battery-charging, lead-acid

I want to charge the 12 V battery of my vehicles (not EVs: car and motorbike), but my vehicles don't have access to the mains. I had the idea to charge the discharged battery (from now on called DISbat) with an external pre-charged AGM battery (from now on called CHGbat) + step-up + potentiometer + MOSFET.

The connections will be:

- CHGbat -> step-up to 14.4 V (or less is better?), since to my knowledge lead-acid 12 V batteries must be charged with 14.4 V.
- step-up -> MOSFET @ 0.7 A -> DISbat. The DISbat will destroy (?) the step-up (rated at 6 A) so the addition of a MOSFET @ 0.7A will keep things cool.
- CHGat -> potentiometer -> MOSFET to control the current of the MOSFET since the motorbike has a 7 Ah battery, but the car has a 40 Ah battery.

Ideally, instead of a potentiometer I can install an Arduino to manually control over time the charging and / or shutdown / float charging after some time.

Do I miss something?

According to this [battery university](https://batteryuniversity.com/article/bu-403-charging-lead-acid) I have to charge in three phases. Obviously I will skip the last phase. But can I also skip the second if I charge at 0.05 C instead at 0.1C ?

I have an AGM charger for the CHGbat.

Comment: AGM is a type of lead-acid battery, not type of charger. You can use it for charge another type of lead-acid battery, but additional control needed. Voltmeter is required.

Comment: Yes it's possible. Design needs some work. Change battery capacities to 7Ah and 40Ah. . Inverter can be current limited to prevent destruction.  Fwiw I have a commercial unit that does exactly this.

Comment: Either uses it a a booster to start the engine,. or use a solar charger instead.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments.

user263983: Yes a voltometer is also in the mix.

@ATCSVOL If you sale in Europe I have interest. I don't want to fully re-charge the DISbat. I will charge the DISbat before deep discharge. The questions are a) can I skip the phases if I charge with 0.05C (or lower). b) my design has fatal flaws? I know that I have to be sure to not overcharge the DISbat.

Jasen: I have a solar charger but I fear for the thieves and it needs too much time and sun to charge. I have the impression that it trickles charges. It's not easy to have the correct angle to the sun.

Comment: From your description hard to understand what kind of equipment you have because you probably not have enough technical background. Better find expert near you who can explain that to do. From my point of view you have everything, you need. Just right connections should be made.

Answer (score 2):

Might be easier and safer to just connect a mains voltage inverter to your charged AGM battery, then plug in a battery charger for your discharged unit. Based on your proposal, you may not quite have the knowledge required to undertake the design safely.

Comment: Where did you get 117V number? Why it can not be 120, 220, or 230?

Comment: @user263983 fair point, I shouldn’t assume OP is in North America, so I’ve edited to “mains voltage”.

Comment: That's exactly my question. There are fatal flaws in the design? They are not easy solvable? The inverter will have some losses and it almost doubles the cost and the hassle.

I know that I have to monitor the charging for overcharging / overheating e.t.c. For that reason I asked if I charge with 0.05C I am in safer side or still in the danger zone?

I liked the idea of the inverter, although the charger will work double time and my charger is 5A and it will fast charge my 7Ah battery.

Answer (score 0):

The solution came from the RC community. They want remote charging so they have some chargers. It was difficult to find a charger that charges Pb batteries.

Plus the requirements of charging are complicated to make your own circuit if you want unattended charging so I used this charger. It charges your battery and the this battery became the source energy for the discharged battery.

Already tested and working. This is my 2nd charging of the donor.

You can use XT60 connectors for Source AND Input. I soldered some crocodile (alligator) clips to XT60 to charge the discharged battery.

The problem is that I have to visit the car around 4 times to fully charged it. My donor battery is 10Ah and the car has 40Ah.

The only problem is that this charger refuses to charge deep discharged batteries. I first charged the battery with a Noco 5 charger for some seconds and the continued with the RC max charger at 0.8A

Another one problem is the very loud annoying beep when it detects an error.

[image: Charging the donor battery]